# Jmeter 4.0 script recording issue

Tags: jmeter

When i'm trying to record application in Jmeter 4.0 using firefox browser not able to capture HTTP requests. I could see below message in

Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
2018-04-20 17:26:36,369 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [50777]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Could you please help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even I have tried importing jmeter user certificate in browser and recorded the user scenario still complains on keystore generation.Try this if it works

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmeterforwindows/

Answer (score -1):

The error is self-explanatory: you need to add JMeter's self-signed certificate to your browser.

1. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. It is being automatically generated when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Import the certificate into your browser, instructions are different for each browser you can use i.e. [Importing your SSL certificate into your browser](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPT3X_2.1.2/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.admin.doc/doc/admin_import_ssl_cert.html) article as a reference.
3. That's it, you should now be able to record HTTPS traffic.

See [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) for more detailed configuration and troubleshooting instructions.